# How to select only first row?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table

```
Table_A

  link    name
  1       toto 
  2       lulu

Table_B

  link    action   date
  1       OK       01/02/2010 
  1       OK       01/02/2022
  1       OK       01/03/2021
  1       OK       01/02/2025
```

Then i want to do query like

```
Select 
  * 
from 
  Table_A, Table_B 
where
  table_A.link (+)= table_b.link and
  table_b.action (+)= 'OK'
```

the problem is that this query return duplicates

```
link    name    action    date
1       toto    OK        01/02/2010 
1       toto    OK        01/02/2022
1       toto    OK        01/03/2021
1       toto    OK        01/02/2025
2       lulu
```

and i want :

```
link    name    action    date
1       toto    OK        01/02/2025
2       lulu
```

How to do ?

Comment: ....by not using `(+)` symbol for joins for sure

Comment: I get different results from you. It seems your outer join condition is actually `where table_b.link (+)= table_a.link` (as implied by the order the tables appear in the `from` clause) which is equivalent to `from table_a left join table_b`, and not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally better to use ANSI join syntax, but following your lead, I will use the Oracle syntax (with the "plus" operator for outer joins).

First, note that you have the "plus" on the wrong side in the first condition in the `WHERE` clause; you need "fictitious" rows added to `table_B`, not to `table_A`.

Then, it is generally best to do the aggregation first, if it depends on just one table. This is what I do in the subquery in the `FROM` clause below.

Also, `date` is an Oracle keyword, and it should not be used as a column name. I hope you are not using it that way. For my code, I assumed the column name is `dt`.

```
select a.link, a.name, b.action, b.dt
from   table_a a,
       ( select link, 'OK' action, max(dt) dt
         from   table_b
         where  action = 'OK'
         group  by link
       ) b
where  b.link (+) = a.link
;
```

Comment: It's close to this, however i need one more field and: select link, 'OK' action, ONE_MORE_FIELD, max(dt) dt
         from   table_b
         where  action = 'OK'
         group  by link 
return me is not a GROUP BY expression :(

Comment: @Stephane - I don't see anything about that in your original post. Sorry, I can't read minds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Distinct` statement: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/distinct.php to select unique data. 
 
Also check out the `Group By` statement: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/group_by.php to group by certain columns, for example to select unique names:

```sql
Select 
  * 
from 
  Table_A, Table_B 
where
  table_A.link (+)= table_b.link and
  table_b.action (+)= 'OK'
group by table_A.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` window analytic function

```
Select link, name, action, "date"
  From
  (
   Select a.link, a.name, b.action, b."date",
          row_number() over (partition by a.link order by b."date" desc ) as rn
     From Table_A a
     Left Join Table_B b 
       on a.link = b.link
      and b.action = 'OK' 
  )
  Where rn = 1;

LINK  NAME  ACTION  date
----  ----- ------  ----------
1     toto  OK      01.02.2025
2     lulu  NULL    NULL
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/EVYO72644)</kbd>

*P.S. Evidently, I don't suggest old comma-seperated join syntax, whereas I do ANSI-92 SQL syntax as in the above query. Another remark that Oracle DB's SQL doesn't require an alias for the subquery, but most of the other DBMS does.*

Answer (score 0):

Use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax!

A simple way to write the query:

```
Select a.*, b.*
from Table_A a left join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by b.link order by b.date desc) as seqnum
      from Table_B b
      where b.action = 'OK'
     ) b
     on b.link = a.link and b.seqnum = 1;
```

Or use aggregation:

```
Select a.link, a.name, b.action, max(b.date)
from Table_A a left join
     Table_B b
     on b.link = a.link and b.action = 'OK'
group by a.link, a.name, b.action
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Use key word GROUP BY

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/group_by.php

2) For date good practice is use format: YYYY-MM-dd

```
link action date
1    OK     2010-02-01
```

For displaying:

```
link name action date
1    toto OK     2025-02-01
2    lulu        2023-03-01
```

insert lulu entry in Table_b

My Table_b:

```
link  action  date
1     OK      2010-02-01
1     OK      2022-02-01
1     OK      2021-03-01
1     OK      2025-02-01
2             2023-03-01
```

3) Try this query (Mysql syntax):

```
SELECT 
  Table_A.link, Table_a.name, action, MAX(date) AS date
FROM 
  Table_A, Table_B 
WHERE
  Table_A.link = Table_B.link
  GROUP BY name
  ORDER BY link;
```